# How to extract several symbols/substrings inside quoted text using regex

Tags: regex

There is the string with some substrings which wrapped by quotes.How to extract comma**s** inside all substrings?

For example, given string with two substrings:

aaa, '`aa,bb,cc,d`', ccc, ddd, '`fddsfdfdf,dfds,fd,f`', ggg

Need to get commas inside quoted substrings:

aaa, 'aa`,`bb`,`cc`,`d', ccc, ddd, 'fddsfdfdf`,`dfds`,`fd`,`f', ggg

---

I came up with this regex-expression but it is wrong:

```regex
('((.*?)(?<comma>,)(.*?))')
```

Comment: What problem are you actually trying to solve here?  Note that in general you should be using a CSV parser here, not regex.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it is just the example, not related to csv.

Comment: Try this (if your regex engine supports look back): (?<='.*?),(?=.*?')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this regex expression. `(?<=^([^']*'[^']*')*[^']*'[^']*),`

[This is a demo.](https://regex101.com/r/Tqytkx/1)

This is better. `,(?=[^']*'(?:[^']*'[^']*')*[^']*$)`

[This is a demo.](https://regex101.com/r/Tqytkx/2)

Answer (score 0):

```
// PHP 5.3.0+

$subject = "aaa, 'aa,bb,cc,d', ccc, ddd, 'fddsfdfdf,dfds,fd,f', ggg";
$pattern = "/'[^']+'/";
preg_replace_callback($pattern, function($data){
    echo preg_filter('/[^,]+/','', $data[0]);
}, $subject);

// Output: ,,,,,,
```